# How to split string according to regex in bash script

Tags: python, regex, bash, split

I have such a string:

```
msg='123abc456def'
```

Now I need to split `msg` and get the result as below:

```
['123', 'abc', '456', 'def']
```

In python, I can do like this:

```
pattern = re.compile(r'(\d+)')
res = pattern.split(msg)[1:]
```

How to get the same result in bash script?
I've tried like this but it doesn't work:

```
IFS='[0-9]'    # how to define IFS with regex?
echo ${msg[@]}
```

Comment: Why not just call your Python script?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Getting the substrings with `grep`, and putting the output in an array using command substitution:

```
$ msg='123abc456def'

$ out=( $(grep -Eo '[[:digit:]]+|[^[:digit:]]+' <<<"$msg") )

$ echo "${out[0]}"
123

$ echo "${out[1]}"
abc

$ echo "${out[@]}"
123 abc 456 def
```

- The Regex (ERE) pattern `[[:digit:]]+|[^[:digit:]]+` matches one or more digits (`[[:digit:]]+`) OR (`|`) one or more non-digits (`[^[:digit:]]+`.

Answer (score 4):

Given that you already know how to solve this in Python, you can solve it using the code shown in the question:

```
MSG=123abc456def;
python -c "import re; print('\n'.join(re.split(r'(\\d+)', '${MSG}')[1:]))"
```

While `python` is not as standard of an executable as say `grep` or `awk`, does that really matter to you?

Comment: Thanks!  Can I use this in bash script when I have a list of string (each in a newline) from bash pipeline?

Comment: @Nikhil. Please ask a new and specific question. Feel free to ping me if you want me to take a look when you do.

Answer (score 3):

I would do matching instead of splitting. Here, I used `grep` but you can use the same regex in pure bash also.

```
$ msg='123abc456def'
$ grep -oE '[0-9]+|[^0-9]+' <<<$msg
123
abc
456
def
```